# Executing threads in a Threadgroup serially in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently learning basics  of Threads in Java and I am trying to write a program simulating a 2x200 Relay race with 2 teams. I would like to have 2 teams (represented by a ThreadGroup each) and each team has 2 members, each of which must run for 200 m. Here running is just simulated by looping in a for loop and printing. I am not able to find a straight forward way of **running threads in a Threadgroup in serially**

Here is how the worker looks like

```
public class RelayRunner implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();

        if (i % 50 == 0) {
            System.out.format("%s ran %d m \n", name, i);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is how the main program looks like

```
public class RelayRunnerMatch {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    RelayRunner relayRunner = new RelayRunner();

    ThreadGroup usa = new ThreadGroup("USA");
    ThreadGroup germany = new ThreadGroup("GERMANY");

    Thread usa1 = new Thread(usa, relayRunner, "usa1");
    Thread germany1 = new Thread(germany, relayRunner, "germany1");

    Thread usa2 = new Thread(usa, relayRunner, "usa2");
    Thread germany2 = new Thread(germany, relayRunner, "germany2");

    usa1.start();
    germany1.start();

    /* Now I would like to start the second thread in a group only if the first 
       thread in the same group has finished like in a real relay race. How??
    */
    //usa1.join(); germany1.join();
    //usa2.start(); germany2.start()  --> Not good, usa2 must start immediately when usa1 has finished
}
```

}

I am not able to see how the join() may be of any help here as it will wait for both threads to finish before the second set of runners can start their run. Also I realize that activeCount() is just an estimate, so I am not sure of using that either.
Is there a solution possible without resorting to services in new Concurrent API(as I haven't reached that further)?

Comment: why use threads if you want things to run serially, that doesn't make any sense and is completely counter to why you would run things in threads to begin with, which is to achieve concurrency.

Comment: That is what I tried to explain, I am trying to simulate a race. Actually threads in each thread group must run in parallel. e.g. usa1 and germany1 starts at the same time and if usa1 finishes first, usa2 starts and so on

Comment: You don't need to have 4 threads for that, and `ThreadGroup` isn't meant to be used the way you try to. Just create two threads, `usa` and `germany`, which will print their start and finish timestamps as many times as there are members (or start-finish intervals).

Comment: You are applying learning effort to a wrong spot. Thread groups are an outdated mechanism and Effective Java has a whole item called "Avoid thread groups". You should also avoid raw thread creation and use Executor Services. Your idea can be implemented with two single-threaded executors, each of which gets two tasks submitted for execution.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I am probably being misguided by an old Tutorial it looks like. But as my knowledge of Thread basics are rather limited, I decided to avoid using higher level abstractions at this point.

Comment: @zencv Thread groups are such a higher-level abstraction, but one which is de facto deprecated. At least focus on raw threads alone; you'll never need to use the `ThreadGroup` API in real projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Player1 implements Runnable{
    private final CountDownLatch countDownLatch;
    private final String s;
    public Player1(CountDownLatch c, String s){
        this.countDownLatch=c;
        this.s=s;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
            System.out.println(s+":"+i);
        }
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }

}


public class Player2 implements Runnable{
    private final CountDownLatch countDownLatch;
    private final String s;
    public Player2(CountDownLatch c, String s){
        this.countDownLatch = c;
        this.s=s;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Player2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
            System.out.println(s+":"+i);
        }
    }
}
```

**Driver program:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread[] grp1 = new Thread[2];
    Thread[] grp2 = new Thread[2];
    CountDownLatch c1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
    CountDownLatch c2 = new CountDownLatch(1);

    grp1[0]=new Thread(new Player1(c1, "grp1:player1"));
    grp1[1]=new Thread(new Player2(c2, "grp1:player2"));


    grp2[0]=new Thread(new Player1(c2, "grp2:player1"));
    grp2[1]=new Thread(new Player2(c2, "grp2:player2"));

    grp1[0].start();
    grp2[0].start();
    grp1[1].start();
    grp2[1].start();
}
```

Comment: i'm choosing your answer for giving me a hint on how to use countdownlatch to solve this. With countdownlatch, probably i no longer need to rely on lower level stuffs like wait, notify etc. Nevertheless, part of my question is also how to logically group threads inorder to also give them common behaviour. In this ex., it it rather trivial and only thing needed is a group name, but let us say, you want to create a biased race whereby a whole group must run with lower priority. Here using arrays or lists of threads seems unhelpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could create two baton-objects and `synchronize` on the respective baton so the second thread would have to wait until the first one releases the baton - or use some locks from `java.util.concurrent.locks`-package to achieve the same. But your relay-members will compete in who gets the baton first or next and you can't define some real order.

But as Jarrod said: when you have several tasks that have to be executed sequentially you better execute them on the same thread: have some runner-objects and add them to a queue on the respective relay-thread that calls their run-method one after the other.